# Creating relationships in Prisma

Tags: database, next.js, orm, relationship, prisma

I am creating a database with the help of Prisma and I have encountered a problem. I have 2 models: User and Lesson. In Lesson I store the IDs of the users who participated in it and the ID of the trainer, which is also a User model. I would like, when downloading Lesson, to be able to immediately get the users who took part in it and the trainer, but not their IDs, but the data of the whole user.

I know I need a relationship, however I can't create one.
My schema.prisma:

```
datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

enum LessonState {
    ACTIVE
    CLOSED
}

model Lesson {
    id          String      @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id") @db.Uuid
    date        DateTime    @default(now())
    subject     String
    description String
    state       LessonState @default(ACTIVE)
    usersIds    String[]    @db.Uuid
    coachId     String      @unique @db.Uuid
}

enum UserRoles {
    ADMIN
    USER
}

model User {
    id        String    @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id") @db.Uuid
    name      String
    surname   String
    password  String
    login     String    @unique
    birthDate DateTime
    role      UserRoles @default(USER)
    createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

I care about one-way relationships, but from what I've found out, Prisma does not allow such, so if necessary they can be two-way. As for the choice of postgresql it is, you could say, random - if some other system allows to do what I need I can switch to it. The same goes for Prisma - I can use another ORM if it supports what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add relations to solve this issue as following
one to many for coach relation and many to many for lesson users relation

```
// schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgres"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum LessonState {
    ACTIVE
    CLOSED
}

model Lesson {
    id          String      @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id") @db.Uuid
    date        DateTime    @default(now())
    subject     String
    description String
    state       LessonState @default(ACTIVE)
    users       User[]   @relation(name: "lesson_users")
    coachId     String   @db.Uuid
    coach User  @relation(name: "coach", fields: [coachId], references: [id])
}

enum UserRoles {
    ADMIN
    USER
}

model User {
    id        String    @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id") @db.Uuid
    name      String
    surname   String
    password  String
    login     String    @unique
    birthDate DateTime
    role      UserRoles @default(USER)
    createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
    myLessons   Lesson[] @relation(name: "lesson_users")
    lessonsITeach    Lesson[] @relation(name: "coach")
}
```

The following query returns all lessons with a list of the users who participated in it and the the trainer

```
await prisma.lesson.findMany({
  include: {
    users: true,
    coach: true,
  },
});
```

to get ids of users that Lesson participated in lesson

```
await prisma.lesson.findFirst({
      include: {
        users: { select: { id: true } },
        coach: true,
      },
    });
```

[image]

to get all lessons the user participated in and what lessons the user teach

```
await prisma.user.findFirst({
  include: {
    myLessons: true,
    lessonsITeach: true,
  },
});
```

to get only ids

```
await prisma.user.findFirst({
  include: {
    myLessons: { select: { id: true } },
    lessonsITeach: { select: { id: true } },
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, how is Lesson supposed to know which users have participated? The IDs are not stored anywhere. In addition, a coach can participate in multiple lessons, and User->lesson stores only one value.

Comment: how is Lesson supposed to know which users have participated? The IDs are not stored anywhere.
-> from the relation itself you can get ids

a coach can participate in multiple lessons
-> in this situation you need to convert the relation to one to many

Comment: Sorry, I am not well familiar with databases - I came here from the frontend :) Could you explain in more detail how it works? I would like to understand it in detail

Comment: @zerakot I edited the answer to match your requirements

Comment: @zerakot for more details [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations)